# Represent derivation as a standard matrix (Linear mapping)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

Given a matrix $a$ of coefficients $\left( \begin{array}{cc} a_0 \\ a_1 \\ .. \\a_n\end{array} \right)$representing $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + ... a_n x^n$, how can I find a standard matrix D such that $[D] a$ will give me the coefficient matrix of the derivative of $a$?

So the dimensions of D will be (n+1) by (n+1).

I've tried to find a D using the standard basis of $R^{n+1}$ but that would just leave me with a zero matrix as D.

For example, $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1\\ 0\\ .. \\0\end{array} \right)$ would just leave me with $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0\\ 0\\ .. \\0\end{array} \right)$
because the next term is set to $0$ per this basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though in a different context, I think I have answered your question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676275/how-to-think-about-the-elements-of-fm-in-terms-of-a-matrix-representation/676311#676311).

Comment: oh my god i can't believe i missed that. Thanks! Also, is there a way of writing the derivation of the basis matrices in more detail (steps)?